# Prove that $\sum_{j1=0}^{n} r_{j}e^{i\cdot 13\theta} = 123$ for any irational $\cos\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that for any $\cos 2$ that its value is a rational number, there are always some non-nesgative integers $r_j$ such that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} r_{j}e^{i\cdot j\taheta} = 0$$
23
For instance, say $\cos \theta = -\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: If you allow *non-negative* integers it will always be possible to choose $\;r_j=0\,\;\forall\,j\;$ and then the result is boringly true...

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry I forgot to put the limitation that a$r_j = 0$ for any $j$ is not allowed.

Comment: Fails for $\theta=0$.  If you disallow $\cos\theta=1$, then $\cos n\theta$ is a native rational for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so you are done.

Comment: @李若谷 What is $\;ar_j\;$ ??

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean $r_j$ sorry

Comment: @李若谷 Then write "for positive,,,", not merely "for non-negative..."

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean $r_j$ can be $0$, but disallowing all $r_j$ to be $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $l=0$, you can also address $\cos\theta=0$. The case $\cos\theta>0$ needs a sign change in $l$; it amounts to proving if $k,\,l$ are positive integers with $k\ge l$ then $k-2lz+kz^2$ divides some nonzero polynomial in $z$ with non-negative integer coefficients. Since$$k(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta})|k(z^n-e^{in\theta})(z^n-e^{-in\theta})=kz^{2n}-(2k\cos n\theta)z^n+k,$$we need only show some $n\in\Bbb N$ satisfies $\cos n\theta\le0$. In fact, we can take $n$ to be a power of $2$: without loss of generality assume $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\,\pi/2)$, so you can double $\theta$ repeatedly until $\theta\in(-\pi,\,\pi)\setminus(-\pi/2,\,\pi/2)$.

Edit: except if $\cos\theta=1$, as @aschepler notes. Then $e^{i\theta}=1$ is a root of no nonzero polynomial with non-negative integer coefficients.